# Can anyone explain why im getting this out put for my prolog Query

Tags: prolog

```
% comment the next two lines out when testing - put back in to submit
:- initialization(q1).
:- initialization(q2).
:- initialization(q3).
:- initialization(end). 
% FACTS. 
mammal(kitty).
mammal(ratatat).
mammal(fido).
claws(kitty).
tail(ratatat).
bestfriend(fido).
feathers(tweety). 
% 9 RULES. 
% If X is a mammal then X has fur. 
fur(X) :- mammal(X).
% If X has fur and X has a tail then X is a rat. 
rat(X) :- fur(X),tail(X).
% If X has claws and X has fur then X is a cat.
cat(X) :- claws(X),fur(X).
% If X is a cat then X meows.
meows(X) :- cat(X).
% If X has feathers then X is a bird.
bird(X) :- feathers(X).
% If X is a bestfriend and X has fur then X is a dog.
dog(X) :- bestfriend(X),fur(X).
% If X is a dog and Y meows then X likes Y.
likes(X,Y) :- dog(X),meows(Y).
% If X is a cat and Y is a bird then X likes Y.
likes(X,Y) :- cat(X),bird(Y).
% If X is a cat and Y is a rat then X likes Y.
likes(X,Y) :- cat(X),rat(Y). 
writeln(T) :- write(T), nl. 
max(X,Y,Z) :-
  X > Y,
  X > Z,
  write(X).
max(X,Y,Z) :-
  X > Y,
  write(Z).
max(_,Y,Z) :-
  Y > Z,
  write(Y).
max(_,_,Z) :-
  write(Z).
moves(N,R) :-
N = 0, R is 0.
moves(N,R) :-
N = 1, R is 1.
moves(N,R) :-
N > 1, T1 is N - 1, T2 is N-1, moves(T1,R1), moves(T2,R2), R is R1 + R2 + 1. 
% QUERY. Uncomment after you have written all predicates.
q1 :- writeln('Who likes whom?'), 
      findall(X, (likes(X,Y), format('~w ~w~n',[X,Y])),_).
q2 :- write('Move cnt for 5: '),
      findall(X, (moves(5,X), format('~w' ,[X])),_).
q3 :-nl, write( 'Max(7,3,9)? '),
      findall(X, (max(7,3,9), format('~w ~n' ,[X])),_).
end :- writeln('done.'), halt.
```

output: 
Who likes whom? 
fido kitty 
kitty tweety 
kitty ratatat 
Move cnt for 5: 31 
Max(7,3,9)? 9_13 <---- why is it printing and underscore 13?
9_13  <---  also why is it printing this line again? 
done.

not sure why its printing the way it is any info would be greatly appreciated! im thinking it has to do with my q3 query but i have been messing with it and cant figure it out thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

q3 has in common with q1,q2 an unusual usage of findall/3 (I think you should use [forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2)/2, really). Differently than other 2 queries, q3 outputs an unbounded variable (X doesn't appear in findall **goal**), and it does 2 times because max/3 succeeds 2 times. Here is the q3 pertinent trace, obtained (in swipl) adding a directive `:- initialization((leash(-all),trace)).`. In gprolog, it's `:- initialization((leash(none),trace)).`

```
   Call: (20) q3
   Call: (21) nl

   Exit: (21) nl
   Call: (21) write('Max(7,3,9)? ')
Max(7,3,9)? 
   Exit: (21) write('Max(7,3,9)? ')
^  Call: (21) findall(_G1900,  (max(7, 3, 9), format('~w ~n', [_G1900])), _G1912)
   Call: (27) max(7, 3, 9)
   Call: (28) 7>3
   Exit: (28) 7>3
   Call: (28) 7>9
   Fail: (28) 7>9
   Redo: (27) max(7, 3, 9)
   Call: (28) 7>3
   Exit: (28) 7>3
   Call: (28) write(9)
9
   Exit: (28) write(9)
   Exit: (27) max(7, 3, 9)
^  Call: (27) format('~w ~n', [_G1900])
_G1900 
^  Exit: (27) format('~w ~n', [_G1900])
   Redo: (27) max(7, 3, 9)
   Call: (28) 3>9
   Fail: (28) 3>9
   Redo: (27) max(7, 3, 9)
   Call: (28) write(9)
9
   Exit: (28) write(9)
   Exit: (27) max(7, 3, 9)
^  Call: (27) format('~w ~n', [_G1900])
_G1900 
^  Exit: (27) format('~w ~n', [_G1900])
^  Exit: (21) findall(_G1900, user: (max(7, 3, 9), format('~w ~n', [_G1900])), [_G1923, _G1920])
   Exit: (20) q3
```

Comment: can you provide and example of you to use the forall/2 i attempted to but i keep getting errors i'm not sure how to use the syntax correctly

Comment: sure: `q1 :- writeln('Who likes whom?'), forall(likes(X,Y), format('~w ~w~n',[X,Y])).`

Comment: q3 :- n1, wrtieln( 'Max(7,3,9) ? '), forall(max(7,3,9)). any idea why this isnt working im not sure how to implement it on forall on the max function since im not supposed to be using x how would the format statement work? @CapelliC

Comment: maybe `q3 :- nl,forall(max(7,3,9),writeln(max(7,3,9))).` but of course, max/3 is buggy. It should fail !

Comment: hey i been trying to fix my max function output since we talked last with no success is there any way you can help me figure out a better algorithm to find the max of 3 numbers in prolog? thanks!

Comment: Oh, maybe now I understand your problem... in Prolog there are not functions, but relations. So, you would need max(7,3,9,9) - output argument is last by convention. I think your best bet is have a more general relation list_max([7,3,9],9).

Comment: sorry i should have known not to say function. The only problem is im required to use two different relations in order to solve this problem my  prompt ask for this. Predicate rules to compute the maximum of three numbers. Example: 
       max3(5,10,3,X). should return 10.  
   Hint: code a max2(X,Y,R) that max3 can use.

Comment: `max2(X,Y,M) :- X > Y -> M = X ; M = Y. max3(A,B,C,M) :- max2(A,B,N),max2(N,C,M).`

Comment: should the rule be written in this exact way or should max3 come first fallowed by max2 ?

Comment: and can you explan they ; M = Y part kinda got lost there?

Comment: i get this error when attempting to run query three                        q3 :- nl, write('Max(7,3,9)? '),
      findall(X, (max3(7,3,9,X), format('~w ~n',[X])),_).                             system_error(cannot_catch_throw(error(existence_error(procedure,max/4),findall/3)))

Comment: never mind i am a complete idiot i didnt have the correct relation name on the query thanks! alot it works i understand now that the ; means or and the -> means then if im correct pretty complex code but i understand it a little bit now @CapelliC